# Populating ListView with Custom desjgn using HashMap

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, custom-lists

I have a ListView in the activity MyBets. XML layout below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background = "@color/grey05"
tools:context="com.example.betterapp.MyBets">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background = "@color/betcolor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also have a custom layout for this ListView in the activity SingleBet. XML Layout Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="#49DE56"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/namesofteams"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1.3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Sevilla vs Barcelona"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor= "#585E5E"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Sevilla 3.55"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusofbet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Open"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The custom layout is supposed to look as follows :

```
Teams     Selection      Status
 A-B       A @ 2.3         Open
```

I have used the following code to obtain the Teams and Selection variables which I would like to add.

```
HashMap<Integer,Game> hashmapofgames = new HashMap<Integer, Game>();
        HashMap<Integer, Game> listofgames;
        listofgames = newBet.getlistofgames();
        for (Integer x : listofgames.keySet()) {
            TextView teams = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            String getTeams = listofgames.get(x).getTeams();
            teams.setText(getTeams);
            TextView selectionodds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            String selectedoutcome = listofgames.get(x).getSelection();
            Double selectedoutcomeodds = listofgames.get(x).getSelectedOdds();
            String selectedteam = "";
            if (selectedoutcome == "home") {
                selectedteam = getTeams.substring(0, getTeams.lastIndexOf("-"));
            } else if (selectedoutcome == "draw") {
                selectedteam = "Draw";
            } else if (selectedoutcome == "away") {
                selectedteam = getTeams.substring(getTeams.lastIndexOf("-       ")+1,getTeams.length());
            }
            String selection = (selectedteam + " @" + selectedoutcomeodds);
            Log.d("teams",getTeams);
            Log.d("selected odds",Double.toString(selectedoutcomeodds));
            Log.d("selected team", selectedteam);
            Log.d("selected outcome", selectedoutcome);
            Log.d("selection", selection);
```

This works fine as the output from the Log shows:

```
 29523-29523/com.example.betterapp D/teams﹕     Villareal - Valencia
 29523-29523/com.example.betterapp D/selected odds﹕ 2.5
 29523-29523/com.example.betterapp D/selected team﹕ Valencia
 29523-29523/com.example.betterapp D/selected outcome﹕ away
 29523-29523/com.example.betterapp D/selection﹕ Valencia @2.5
```

My question is how do I populate the listview so that  namesofteams and selection display Teams and Selection. I am calling this method from a seperate class called AllGameslist.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class that extends adapter. Define the custom view their via help of inflater and then set which ever value (if iterating) that you want to set with the help of Map/List that you are pass from the activity/fragment to the adapter class.

Comment: Could you write a short code to demonstrate how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are retrieving details of your users in a json format like [{"username":"StackOverflow","password":"xxxxxx","created":"08 Apr 02:30 2015 PM","id":"15014"},{"username":"StackExchange","password":"xxxxxxxx","created":"09 Apr 02:30 2015 2015 PM","id":"15015"}]
Now, you want to display this in a list view. 
1) Extract this json and set this value in a bean like user.setName(jsonObject.getString("name")); and so on. Then add the object into the ArrayList list.add(user).
2) After iterating over all the data items and populating them in the last pass the list to the adapter which you have defined. 
3) In the adapter, in getView() method set the listview items in the way that you want to and display to the user. You can also implement onItemClick for the item selected by the user.
For further reference: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView